# How to remove spaces of object's keys? [for...in] [keys.forEach] [reduce]

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, transformation, reduce

**My goal:** remove spaces from keys of objects.

**For example, I have such records:**

```
const records = [
    { 'Red Blue': true, 'Orange Strawberry': true, 'Abc Xyz': true },
    { 'Blue Red': true, 'Abc Abc': true, 'Abc Xyz': true },
    { 'Yellow Green': true, 'Apple Banana': true, 'Abc Xyz': true },
]
```

**And have to remove spaces of each key of each record, to be like:**

```
[
    { 'RedBlue': true, 'OrangeStrawberry': true, 'AbcXyz': true },
    { 'BlueRed': true, 'AbcAbc': true, 'AbcXyz': true },
    { 'YellowGreen': true, 'AppleBanana': true, 'AbcXyz': true },
]
```

**Questions:**

1. Am I doing right?
2. Is there another solution that can solve my task?

I wrote 3 solutions: with `for in`, with `Object.keys().forEach` and with `reduce`.

_

### Here 3 solutions of mine:

```js
const records = [
  { "Red Blue": true, "Orange Strawberry": true, "Abc Xyz": true },
  { "Blue Red": true, "Abc Abc": true, "Abc Xyz": true },
  { "Yellow Green": true, "Apple Banana": true, "Abc Xyz": true },
];

/* 1) for...in */
console.time && console.time('solution 1');
const solution1 = records.map(record => {
  const newRecord = {};
  for (const key in record) {
    newRecord[key.replace(/\s/g, "")] = record[key];
  }
  return newRecord;
});
console.timeEnd && console.timeEnd('solution 1');

/* 2) Object.keys(records).forEach */
console.time && console.time('solution 2');
const solution2 = records.map(parent => {
  const newParent = {};
  Object.keys(parent).forEach(key => {
    newParent[key.replace(/\s/g, "")] = parent[key];
  });
  return newParent;
});
console.timeEnd && console.timeEnd('solution 2');

/* 3) reduce */
console.time && console.time('solution 3');
const solution3 = records.map(parent => {
  return Object.keys(parent).reduce((acc, key) => ({
    ...acc,
    [key.replace(/\s/g, "")]: parent[key],
  }), {});
});
console.timeEnd && console.timeEnd('solution 3');

/* All solutions has the same result */
console.log({
  solution1,
  solution2,
  solution3,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**UPDATED:** added `console.time` to measure the execution time of each solution.

Comment: your question is about looping not about removing spaces

Comment: @guijob I suppose you're right in terms of the title, but a question is much better outlying the actually problem-to-be-solved instead of asking about the solution itself - avoiding the XY Problem.

Comment: You asked yourself thrice if you could do it, but you never once asked yourself if you should.

Comment: @Vic Why would removing spaces from property names be anything he "shouldn't do"...? And why not include that in your comment instead of vaguely informing him that you don't approve without providing foundation for such a claim?

Comment: @Vic I've such records and I can't controll them. They always coming like that - and to pass them to another service I have to remove those spaces anyway (I should do it)

Comment: @TylerRoper to not avoid XY problem I wrote 2nd question ;)

Comment: I've just added execution time logging and suprised that `for in`-loop is slower than others - got shocked!

Answer (score 2):

Questions like "what is better" are subjective and the answer is usually "whatever fits you the best as long as it does the trick". However, there's a common consensus that separating code into reusable parts is cleaner in the long run. In your particular example, "modify the keys of some object" and "remove whitespace" are two loosely related parts, which each can be useful on its own, so it's "better" to code them as such, for example:

```
function mapKeys(obj, fn) {
    let res = {};

    for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(obj))
        res[fn(k)] = v;

    return res;
}
```

and

```
let removeSpaces = x => x.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

Then, to solve the problem at hand, you just combine both parts together:

```
newRecords = records.map(rec => mapKeys(rec, removeSpaces))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const records = [
  { "Red Blue": true, "Orange Strawberry": true, "Abc Xyz": true, hello: 'world' },
  { "Blue Red": true, "Abc Abc": true, "Abc Xyz": true },
  { "Yellow Green": true, "Apple Banana": true, "Abc Xyz": true },
]

console.time && console.time('Execution time');
const newRecords = records.map(r => {
  const rKeys = Object.keys(r)
  let refObj = {}
  
  rKeys.forEach(k => {
    let tempKey = k
    
    if (k.indexOf(' ') !== -1) tempKey = k.replace(' ', '')
    
    refObj[tempKey] = r[k]
  })
  
  return refObj
});
console.timeEnd && console.timeEnd('Execution time');

console.log(newRecords)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some regex to remove spaces:

```js
const records = [
    { 'Red Blue': true, 'Orange Strawberry': true, 'Abc Xyz': true },
    { 'Blue Red': true, 'Abc Abc': true, 'Abc Xyz': true },
    { 'Yellow Green': true, 'Apple Banana': true, 'Abc Xyz': true },
]

const noSpaces = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(records).replace(/\s(?=\w.+":)/gm, ''))

console.log(noSpaces)
```